# How do I correct the following in Magento 2.1.2: Fatal error: Call to a member function getId() on null

Tags: error, magento-2.1.2

The path to the file is: `C:\XXX\www\magento212\vendor\magento\framework\View\Model\Layout\Merge.php` on line 751

Here are the Line numbers followed by the code with the actual line **751**

---

```
741  /**  
742  * Find the closest physical theme among ancestors and a theme itself  
743  *  
744  * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Design\ThemeInterface $theme  
745  * @return \Magento\Theme\Model\Theme  
746  * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException  
747  */  
748  protected function _getPhysicalTheme(\Magento\Framework\View\Design\ThemeInterface $theme)  
749   {  
750       $result = $theme;  
751     while ($result->getId() && !$result->isPhysical()) {
752           $result = $result->getParentTheme();  
753       }  
754       if (!$result) {  
755           throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(  
756               new \Magento\Framework\Phrase(  
757                'Unable to find a physical ancestor for a theme \'%1\'.',  
758                   [$theme->getThemeTitle()]  
759               )  
760           );  
761       }  
762       return $result;  
763   }
```

---

I would appreciate some help. Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: I doubt this line is the issue, did you develop a custom theme? If so, does it implement `\Magento\Framework\View\Design\ThemeInterface`?

Comment: I did install a theme from Templatemonster. As to whether it implements \Magento\Framework\View\Design\ThemeInterface, I am not quite sure.

Answer (score 1):

In your theme, find theme.xml and add this after title tag

```
<parent>Magento/blank</parent> <!-- the parent theme, in case your theme inherits from an existing theme -->
```

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check table `theme`. All themes should have `type` set to `0`. Sometimes magento likes to change it to `1` (virtual theme).

Check also if `parent_id` is correct.

Comment: what should be the parent_id for custom theme?

Comment: Usually it should be `Magento/blank` or `Magento/luma`. If you buy a theme, then it would be good to create new one and extend one you bought (parent_id will be id of this bought theme).

Answer (score 0):

Add this before the beginning of the while loop and ensure you are passing a theme object wherever you call it from:

```
if(is_null($result)) {
   throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(  
               new \Magento\Framework\Phrase(  
                'Unable to find a physical ancestor for a theme \'%1\'.',  
                   [$theme->getThemeTitle()]  
               )  
           ); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much for the response, I really do appreciate your time.   How and where do I add this code?   I am a newbie.

Comment: Okay. Here is what I did.  <p>I added the code to the beginning of Line 751 as you suggested. However, I get the following new error, when I do: </p><p> Fatal error: Call to undefined function Magento\Framework\View\Model\Layout\isnull()</p>  I think I am missing something here, but I don't know what it is.

Comment: You can add it on line 751. Sorry, it had to be is_null, not isnull. I've amended the snippet.