# Magento 2 Unable to find a physical ancestor for a theme

Tags: magento2, php, database, theme

I've delete Magento 2 theme folder and upload it again but when upgrade it via command line i've got an error say `Unable to find a physical ancestor for a theme` so any suggestion about that?

Comment: You get this error while setup PWA?

Answer (score 8):

You need to check in database **theme** table column **type** should be 0 for all.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

> You might want to check table theme. All themes should have type set to 0. Sometimes magento likes to change it to 1 (virtual theme).
>
> Check also if parent_id is correct.

[Unable to find a physical ancestor for a theme / How do I correct the following in Magento 2.1.2: Fatal error: Call to a member function getId() on null](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/149323/how-do-i-correct-the-following-in-magento-2-1-2-fatal-error-call-to-a-member-f)

Works like a charm. Fork the database and you're good to go.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to deploy the static content

bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f

Answer (score 0):

> **You need to update the type from the theme table, which may be changed. Please run below SQL**

```
update theme set type=0;
```

[image]

After that, you need to run the below magento command.

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento s:s:d -f 
php bin/magento cache:clean
```

Thanks, Ansar Husain