# Magento 2 How to resolve error: Unable to find a physical ancestor for a theme?

Tags: magento2

When trying to install 'TemplateMonster Theme'I get the error on the frontend:

```
"Unable to find a physical ancestor for a theme 'TemplateMonster Theme'.","1":"#0 \/lib\/internal\/Magento\/Framework\/View\/Model\/Layout\/Merge.php(713):"
```

In the same moment backend of the site working.

I do all steps required in the install [guide](https://www.templatemonster.com/help/quick-start-guide/magento-themes/v4-0/index.php?lang=en&section=theme-installation#) but that's guide not helped me.

So I think maybe I missed something and tryed to use theme dump which I find in the 'TemplateMonster Theme' folder.
And unsuccessfull...

The only way to displayed my magento2 site it's switch back to the default theme.

Little notice - my current magento site version is 2.2.5, theme demo site works perfect on the version 2.0.2.

P.S. I'm allready read same [post](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/149323/how-do-i-correct-the-following-in-magento-2-1-2-fatal-error-call-to-a-member-f) and that's not helped me:

For any tips I will be very grateful!!!

Answer (score 0):

For me the cause of the problem was the database. I check type and theme_if of my themes and then 
`$UPDATE theme SET type=0 WHERE theme_id IN (4, 5);`

Look also in this anwser
[Magento 2 Unable to find a physical ancestor for a theme](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/235464/magento-2-unable-to-find-a-physical-ancestor-for-a-theme?rq=1)